# Issue with JavaScript in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

We are using woo and the woo filter for products. I hooked it up on this test page and I am trying to change images on chekckbox of color… still in early testing.

at this point the code, right now as testing on the page, you check the color box and in console it will write the value.

here is my test on codepen:

```
    function getSelectedCheckboxValues(name) {
    const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(`input[name="${name}"]:checked`);
    let values = [];
    checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
        values.push(checkbox.value);
      
    });
    return values;
    console.log(getSelectedCheckboxValues('color-checks'));
}
  //let result = document.querySelector('#result');
   document.body.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
   let target = e.target;
   console.log(getSelectedCheckboxValues('color-checks'));
   });
```

https://codepen.io/hjmoore420/pen/YzwgGRN

on codepen the HTML is rendered code from the Filter test page.

it is working there. I did find some issues on the live page, but have fixed them. At this point I am just trying to get the value of the checkbox to write to the console.

I went to debug and found not issues, changed themes and it did not work. the code is just straight JS nothing crazy.

Any help will be appreciated.

The page I need help with: https://www.outdoordogsupply.com/filter-dog-collars/

Comment: That is fairly simple.. the name of your inputs in the actual project is `colors-check` and not `color-checks`.

Comment: on the actual live page I am using 

https://www.outdoordogsupply.com/filter-dog-collars/

console.log(getSelectedCheckboxValues('colors-check'));

I may have copied over the code from the codepen and I had started with another page that had the different values, thanks for the response though.

Comment: as I am testing this morning in console if you run: 
console.log(getSelectedCheckboxValues('colors-check'));
you can see the values exist, it is just not being written to the console without requesting. I have not seen that behavior before but the values are being passed. This may be enough for me to test next steps. Any input will still be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end code is essentially the same as where I started, I changed the last event call to click and it worked as expected:

```
 function getSelectedCheckboxValues(name) {
  const checkboxes = 
  document.querySelectorAll(`input[name="${name}"]:checked`);
  let values = [];
   checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
    values.push(checkbox.value);
  
   });
  return values;
  }

  document.body.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
console.log(getSelectedCheckboxValues('colors-check'));
});
```

in another forum there was a belief that another event handler on this same item may have been the culprit, but this worked well for this stage, now on to the next phase.